# What is the maximum number of edges in G?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Trying to study some Graph Theory on my own and I came across this question in Combinatorics and Graph Theory by John Harris et al.

"If G is a graph of order n, what is the maximum number of edges in G?"

My rough attempt at an answer is that the maximum number of edges would occur in a Complete Graph $K_n$. Each vertex has a degree n-1. Hence the total number of degrees will be n(n-1). Given the first Theorem of Graph Theory/The Degree-Edge relation, we know that $\sum dg(v)$ where v is a vertex is equivalent to twice the number of edges. Would that mean the answer is $|E| = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ ? If it is what other ways may we arrive at the same conclusion?

By graph I mean simple and undirected.

Comment: Why don't you try it for a few small values of $n$, and see what happens?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Seems to work for smaller values.

Comment: If you are referring to undirected simple graphs (undirected graphs without multiple edges or self-loops) then your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis thanks. In case I wanted to prove this holds for n greater than or equal to 1 what would the inductive step look like?

Comment: @Onlyartist9 I don't see the reason to use induction here.

Comment: The easiest way to get there is to see that the number of edges is at most the number of pairs of vertices, which is $n\choose2$, which is $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson